# Rails assets pipeline causing problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I am trying to get tiny_mce to work with my Rails 3.1 application and its almost works.

I have it installed in vendor/assets/tiny_mce and included in my application.js bootstrap:

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require tiny_mce

tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector : "mce_editor"
});
```

Now when I view my page with ?debug_assets=true then it doesn't combine the files with sprockets and everything works as expected. However if I get rid of the ?debug_assets=true then it no longer works.

It seems that TinyMce automatically loads a few additional js files (lang files etc) when needed but this doesn't seem to work with rails 3.1. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks for your suggestion, I checked the request logs and the needed files were:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/home_pages/4/langs/en.js"):

and 

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/home_pages/4/themes/simple/editor_template.js"):
```

There dozens of different js files in tiny_mce and I am assuming it loads a different set based on which configs you initialise it with. **Should I just manually require these extra js files one at a time to my application.js file until rails stops complaining or is there a more general or best practices solution?** Thanks

Comment: Did you check the request log to see how TinyMCE is requiring these files? Which URL it is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Install](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) the `tinymce-rails` gem - it's worked well for me in the past.  Delete the tiny_mce folder from your assets/javascripts folder.

Change your manifest to this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require tinymce
//= require_tree .
```

and it's better to move this to `main.js`

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector : "mce_editor"
});
```