# Rails, Template error

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some problem on my production server.
On my local everything work great. Error in production.log:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.2 at 2012-11-27 21:30:39 +0100
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_heads-main.html.erb (1.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

ActionView::Template::Error (modern.css isn't precompiled):
    1:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    2:     <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Zapust.pl - życie granicy, przejścia graniczne, kamery, chat" %></title>
    3:     <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Zapust.pl - życie granicy, przejści$
    4:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag("modern") %>
    5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag("front") %>
    6:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag("modern-responsive") %>
    7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag("popup") %>
  app/views/layouts/_heads-main.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__heads_main_html_erb__3671184199177623191_17240242720'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__829205250877960417_17238366080'
```

I have compile option set to true in my config. On the screen in webbrowser:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

I have even deleted application layout file and I am still getting this error. 
tmp/cache is empty. Where is the cache ? What is wrong ?

Error with  command bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace:

```
rake aborted!
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/app/assets/javascripts/tiny_mce/plugins/spellchecker/editor_plugin.js has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:18:in `block in read_unicode'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:12:in `tap'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:12:in `read_unicode'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:171:in `evaluate'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `new'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `block in build_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:262:in `circular_call_protection'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:240:in `build_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:106:in `block in build_required_assets'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:100:in `each'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:100:in `build_required_assets'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `new'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `block in build_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:262:in `circular_call_protection'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:240:in `build_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `new'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `build_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:23:in `block in compile'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/mydevil/ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/mydevil/ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/mydevil/ruby19/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/mydevil/ruby19/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/mydevil/ruby19/bin/ruby19 /usr/...]
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/mydevil/ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/home/mitchpolska/domains/zapust.pl/public_ror/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/mydevil/ruby19/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/mydevil/ruby19/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: Did you run `rake assets:precompile` on the production server?

Comment: Yes I have errors:
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/mydevil/ruby19/bin/ruby19 /usr/...]

Comment: re-run it with `--trace` and add the error trace to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of tiny mce has an invalid character somewhere that makes the asset precompilation crash.

Use the tiny mce gem as suggested here : [Rails assets pipeline causing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890368/rails-assets-pipeline-causing-problems)

Or, try to find a version of tiny mce that works with the asset pipeline